# connecting bluetooth pan profile via api

Tags: android, api, bluetooth

I tried to build a little proof-of-concept app for my company using the bluetooth API on android 4.0.3. (using the android.bluetooth package)
we need to connect to a measuring instrument via bluetooth, the only profile supported by  the instrument is PAN.

My problem is - when I browse through the SDK(version 15) sources, there is a BluetoothPan.java file that implements this profile and there also is a PAN-Profile constant defined in the BluetoothProfile.java source file. 

BUT - when I set up an android-project in eclipse, targetting the SDK version 15 and try to use that profile class, there is no BluetoothPan class available in the android.bluetooth package
and the BluetoothProfile class does not contain the PAN constant.
Besides, the SDK documentation also does not contain any information on this class.
Can somebody explain this to me? The source is available but it's not compiled into the package?
are there different branches of the SDK I did not recognize?
I'm really puzzeled.

Answer (score 2):

these are internal APIs (they are marked with @hide in the javadocs).

http://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/18/using-com-android-internal-part-1-introduction/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, these are internal APIs and you can reach them by importing external jar. After importing it, you should right click jar file and choose "add as librar". After that, you can import BluetoothPan and other internal APIs. You can download jar:

https://sites.google.com/site/hippunosource/home/android/androidnohide-apiwo-shi-yongsuru-rifurekushonha-wei-shi-yong

I am sure, it helps you!